# issus in memory managemant with json object

Tags: android, json, out-of-memory

I have a memory management problem at "Odoo_database_json"  when I sync it from odoo server as it receives a huge JSON object from the odoo server that includes an image, giving me an out of memory error.

I have tried things like garbage collection, trimming memory, and bitmap recycle().

```
public class Databasetask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Odoo o = new Odoo("http://10.0.2.2:8089");
            JSONArray database_list = o.getDatabaseList();
            Log.e("database_list.", database_list.toString());

            // Log.e("qqqqqqqqqq.", j1.toString());
            o.authenticate("admin", "a", "demo");// =========>aa set karvanu
            // che

            JSONArray fields = new JSONArray();
            fields.put("city");
            fields.put("name");
            fields.put("phone");
            fields.put("image");
            fields.put("create_date");
            fields.put("write_date");

            // android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData("com.serpentcs.AIOS8.hprof");
            // Debug.dumpHprofData("com.serpentcs.AIOS8.hprof");
            // System.gc();

            JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
            jsonParams.put("fields", fields);

            // Odoo_database_json=null;
            //==================================================================Error at here because of heap momory is full when i sync data from Odoo server
            Odoo_database_json = o.search_read(Modle, jsonParams); //<==error at here

            jsonArray_items = Odoo_database_json.getJSONArray("records");

            // int x = TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE;
            // Log.e("x....",""+x);

            // table exxist ...if u change filed pls..remove it
            tableExist = exists("res_partner");
            Log.e("table", "" + tableExist);
            // if exist does not create table
            if (tableExist) {
                Log.e("Log.....", "Table is exist");

            } else {
                Log.e("Log.....", "Table is not exist");
                JSONObject a = jsonArray_items.getJSONObject(1);

                Iterator<?> key_fields = a.keys();// ===givs fields

                myhelper = new OdooHelper(Listview_contect.this);
                myhelper.makeTable(key_fields);

            }

            // // ==get the records and put it into database..
            //
            publishProgress();
            // //uncaughtException
            // // Log.e("qqqqqqqqqq.", "fgh");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OVersionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

...........................
sorry i dont know how to add new code because i m new ..user..pls any one edit it ..

```
 10-30 13:14:50.692: E/dalvikvm-heap(1419): Out of memory on a 2097168-byte allocation.
10-30 13:14:50.692: I/dalvikvm(1419): "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE
10-30 13:14:50.692: I/dalvikvm(1419):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb4e89628 self=0xb767e758
10-30 13:14:50.692: I/dalvikvm(1419):   | sysTid=1435 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=-1217926224
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   | state=R schedstat=( 22190000000 5900000000 5215 ) utm=2068 stm=151 core=0
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.expandBuffer(Scanner.java:~2067)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.readMore(Scanner.java:2031)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.findDelimiterAfter(Scanner.java:2009)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.setTokenRegion(Scanner.java:1923)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:541)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:519)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at odoo.Odoo.convertStreamToString(Odoo.java:1140)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at odoo.Odoo.requestData(Odoo.java:460)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at odoo.Odoo.search_read(Odoo.java:726)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at odoo.Odoo.search_read(Odoo.java:771)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at com.serpentcs.client.Listview_contect$Databasetask.doInBackground(Listview_contect.java:188)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at com.serpentcs.client.Listview_contect$Databasetask.doInBackground(Listview_contect.java:1)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-30 13:14:50.702: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-30 13:14:50.712: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-30 13:14:50.712: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-30 13:14:50.712: I/dalvikvm(1419):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-30 13:14:50.712: W/System.err(1419): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-30 13:14:50.712: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.expandBuffer(Scanner.java:2067)
10-30 13:14:50.722: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.readMore(Scanner.java:2031)
10-30 13:14:50.722: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.findDelimiterAfter(Scanner.java:2009)
10-30 13:14:50.722: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.setTokenRegion(Scanner.java:1923)
10-30 13:14:50.722: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:541)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:519)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at odoo.Odoo.convertStreamToString(Odoo.java:1140)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at odoo.Odoo.requestData(Odoo.java:460)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at odoo.Odoo.search_read(Odoo.java:726)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at odoo.Odoo.search_read(Odoo.java:771)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at com.serpentcs.client.Listview_contect$Databasetask.doInBackground(Listview_contect.java:188)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at com.serpentcs.client.Listview_contect$Databasetask.doInBackground(Listview_contect.java:1)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-30 13:14:50.732: W/System.err(1419):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Show the crash log (logcat).

Comment: It's not clear what line is causing your problem. You might look at [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) to implement a stream parser so you can skip over the large data fields.

Comment: You can implement paging or can perform lazy loading rather than fetching the whole data.BTW whats the size of the json coming via stream?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar    i want to know how can i clear heap memory every time when activity reload..thanks.

Comment: you can only clear ram/memory after the completion of operation. As you mentioned your Json returns bulk data so you may need to follow the advice mention above. Can you share the link of json?

Comment: for a quick workaround you can set `android:largeHeap = true` inside Manifest, application tag!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar i also added it  but still it not work..
i find some link that it said that use jacson library..
its that correct solution.sir pls..help..
i am suffering its from 6 days..i check all things..

Comment: after reinstalling its work ...first sync but second time its still error...

Comment: Vishal is it possible that you can share the url so that i can see the amount of data. I have no idea about jacson BTW

Comment: Also after first sync are you clearing up all the memory? you may clear up any data structure that is keeping memory for example! or if there are bitmaps use recycle after using them.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar sry, its local server (Odoo) run on my laptop, and sir i also try bitmap recycle,garbage collactor,trim memory,catch clear all things but i am failed. i found every thing and result is HEAP MEMORY full....i increase it to 24 mb then error solve . but i want 16 mb heap memory...